# Struts2 Bootstrap Image Selection

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, struts2, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

I am looking for a image selection like shown here:

https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

But i do not get it work with Struts2 and Bootstrap, because the images are not displayed.

What i did:

- included the .js and .css from git
- imported the .js and .css to my jsp like this

  `<link href="style/image-picker/image-picker.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="style/image-picker/image-picker.js"></script>`
- copied example to my jsp

  `<select class="image-picker show-html">
  <option data-img-src="images/process/xxx.jpg" value="xxx.jpg">  xxx  </option>
  <option data-img-src="images/process/yyy.jpg" value="yyy.jpg">  yyy  </option>
  <option data-img-src="images/process/800_300.png" value="800_300.png">  Default  </option>
  <option data-img-src='http://www.example.com/image.jpg' value='42'>
  </select>`

Do you have any better solution for a image selection or an idea how to get the image picker worked ?

Comment: It's unclear what did you do to get it working.

Comment: The `data-img-src` should be the url of your image, check if the images are on the server and make sure you do not have any `javascript` error by checking browser console.

Comment: if i include the the image directly like `<img class="image_picker_image" src="images/process/ambilight.jpg">` it is displayed but the picker doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but did you fix it?

You should just call the constructor of the imagepicker and then use the on the select.

```
$('.image-picker').imagepicker();
```